# Checking a private field vs catching an exception

Tags: c#, exception

I have a class from a third-party assembly (so I can't edit it):

```
public class MyClass
{
  private bool _loggedIn;
  public void Login() {_loggedIn = true;}
  public void Logout() {
    if (!_loggedIn) throw new InvalidOperationException();
    _loggedIn = false;
   }
}
```

Now, suppose I have an instance of `MyClass` (for which I don't know `_loggedIn`), and I need call `LogOut`. Which of the following methods of avoiding a fatal exception will generally be faster? (any other method would be fine too):

- To call `LogOut`, and if `_loggedIn == false`, just catch the exception
- To use reflection to check that `_loggedIn == true`, and only call `LogOut` if so

Comment: Honestly I'd change that class to expose a `LoggedIn` property, but given the choice I'd personally go with catching the exception.

Comment: We need more context, based on the code I currently see that approach is a horrible one.  You should have better architecture in place to represent the login status of said user.  At the very least, a `Property` you can access.

Comment: Try both and find out for yourself.  Or just avoid the problem and don't try to log out multiple times in the first place.

Comment: @Greg: Yeah, the design of the class stinks. As I just updated the OP, though, it's from a third-party assembly; I can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if your class doesn't expose at least a read-only property for `LoggedIn`, there sounds like a fairly large design flaw.

For speed, using reflection will generally be faster, particularly if you cache the `FieldInfo` or build a `Func<bool>` using `System.Linq.Expressions`. This is because Exceptions collect lots of debug information when thrown, including a `StackTrace`, which can be expensive.

As with anything, though, it is often best to test such operations, as there are sometime optimizations or other factors that may surprise you.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the invariants you expect to see in your application.

**1.** If you expect to have a lot of `MyClass` having different state(logged in, logged off), then it is better to avoid overhead of exception (because exception is **Exceptional** situation) and use some specific public `IsLoggedIn` property (obviously to avoid Reflection) or some `TryXxxxx`-like methods.

And even if you can't modify the original code no one stops you from wrapping it:

```
public class MyWrappedClass
{
    public Boolean IsLoggedIn {get; private set;}
    private MyClass m_Log;

    public MyWrappedClass ()
    {
        this.m_Log = new MyClass();
        this.IsLoggedIn = false;
    }

    public void Log()
    {
          try
          {
              this.m_Log.LogIn();
              this.IsLoggedIn = true;
          }
          catch
          {
              this.IsLoggedIn = false;
          }
    }

    public void LogOut()
    {
        try
        {
            this.m_Log.LogOut();
            this.IsLoggedIn = false;
        }
        catch
        {
            this.IsLoggedIn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You could even go further and implement [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface with it to avoid manual LogIn-LogOut management:

```
public class MyWrappedClass
{
    private class LogSessionToken : IDisposable
    {
        private MyWrappedClass parent;
        public LogSessionToken (MyWrappedClass parent)
        {
            parent.LogIn();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            parent.LogOut();
        }
    }

    public IDisposable LogSession()
    {
        return new LogSessionToken (this);
    }
     // ...
}
```

And use it like

```
using (var logToken = wrappedInstance.LogSession)
{
    // do the work.
} // No need to worry about manual LogOut
```

**2.** If you expect to use only few of `MyClass` in a proper fashion, then it would be a better idea to not handle exception at all - if something wrong happened then it is some programming error thus the program shall be terminated.

Comment: Can you update your answer to reflect the clarification that this class is in a third-party assembly, and I can't update it?

Comment: Option one could be achieved by writing a wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern `if (CanFoo) Foo();` appears very much, that tends to imply very strongly that either:

1. A properly-written client would know when it can or cannot call `Foo`.  The fact that a client doesn't know suggest that it's probably deficient in other ways.
2. The class exposing `CanFoo` and `Foo` should also expose a method which will `Foo` if possible and appropriate (the method should throw if unable to establish expected post-conditions, but should return silently if the post-conditions were established before the call)

In cases where a class one does not control should provide such a method but doesn't, the cleanest approach may be to write one's own wrapper method whose semantics mirror those the missing method should have had.  If a later version of the class implements the missing method, changing one's code to use that implementation may be easier than refactoring lots of `if (CanFoo)` constructs.

BTW, I would suggest that a properly-designed class should allow calling code to indicate whether it is expecting a transition from logged-in state to logged-out state, or whether it wants to end up in logged-out state but it doesn't care how it gets there.  Both kinds of semantics have perfectly legitimate uses; in cases where the first kind would be appropriate, having a `LogOut` method throw an exception if called on a closed session would be a good thing, but in cases where client code merely wants to ensure that it is logged out, having an `EnsureLoggedOut` method that could be invoked unconditionally would be cleaner than having to add extra client-side code for that purpose.